# Import module to test directory

Tags: python, python-3.x, module, anaconda

I want to import business code from my test folder.

I installed my code using `python setup.py install`, which copy the code into the anaconda site-package folder. But I want to test my code in my dev. directory, as I don't want to constantly install my code to test it after any small change.

I am using Anaconda and Spyder IDE.

Here is my dir structure:

```
dev
└── myproject
    ├── setup.py
    ├── myproject
    │   ├── __init__.py
    │   └── myproject.py
    └── test
        ├── __init__.py
        └── test_importprojecthere.py
```

I took it from here: [Running unittest with typical test directory structure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1896918/running-unittest-with-typical-test-directory-structure)

For now, I'm simply trying to import a function.

```
# dev: projectfile.py
def hello():
    print('Hello world!')
```

Here is where I call it from.

```
# dev: test_importprojecthere.py
from myproject.projectfile import hello # Use installed package.
hello()
```

more information:

- [Python relative paths for unit tests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42678513/python-relative-paths-for-unit-tests)
- [Import a module from a relative path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/279237/import-a-module-from-a-relative-path) Not ideal!
- [relative path not working even with __init__.py](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9427037/relative-path-not-working-even-with-init-py)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are **creating** packages, you do not want to install them in your site-packages.

Do not use

- `python setup.py install`

Instead, use

- `python setup.py develop` or...
- `pip install -e .`

Those commands install your setup using [symlinks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbolic_link). Instead of creating a copy, it links to your actual project. So when you modify it, it's being modified instantly everywhere.

Thanks to that, you will not have to update/install or do anything to run your unit tests.

-- *"But now, every time I modify my package, everything using it might break. I don't want to break my production code!"*

Do not worry! This is the reason why we use virtual environments. When you create a package, make sure you create a virtual environment, that you might name, by example "myproject_dev".

In the dev. env. use `python setup.py develop` so that you can develop on it.

In the prod. env. use `python setup.py install`, so that you use a copy, that will not suddenly change. You won't modify it, because in prod, you consume your package, you don't develop on it! Keeps things simple an safe.